# If Statement to stop character falling through ground

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite

I'm making a platform and want to stop the character (a ball) from going through the ground.

Can I write an if statement similar to `if (Ball.center.y == 463) Ball.center.y = 463;`?

`463` is the `y` position that the ground is in the game.

Answer (score 3):

While that approach is certainly possible, typically you want to abstract away the details (such as the 463 y-position of the ground) so that your code is more robust. For example, if you changed the y-position of the ground, you would have to change the 463 value everywhere you use it!

But fundamentally, yes you would use an if statement somewhat like what you provided. One thing to note is that if the ground is at 463, your ball will be half-way through the ground (since you are looking at the y-position of the *centre* of the ball.

Moreso, you want a check that is not so absolute... what if the position of the ball somehow becomes lower than the ground? Say 462? What should the behavior be now?

Without getting into the physics and design of your program, you would at the very least want to change your statement to something like:

```
int ball_lower_bound = Ball.center.y - Ball.height/2;
int ground_bound = 463;
if (ball_lower_bound < ground_bound) { 
  ball_lower_bound = ground_bound;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, I will paste my code for the ball motion here as I have not included a Ball.height as such.

Comment: -(void)BallMoving{
    
    Ball.center = CGPointMake(Ball.center.x, Ball.center.y - BallFlight);
    
    BallFlight = BallFlight - 4;
    
    if (BallFlight < -15) {
        BallFlight = -15;
    }

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using sprite kit you should use physics body to handle that.
This is in swift:
variables of your class:

```
let balCategory:UInt32 = 1 << 0
let groundCategory:UInt32 = 1 << 1
```

Then when you define your ball sprite:

```
ball.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = ballCategory
ball.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = groundCategory
ball.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = groundCategory
```

Then when you define your ground sprite (hopefully you have a image for your ground, if not make a very thin transparent or have something just below the screens edge):

```
ground.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = groundCategory
ground.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = ballCategory
ground.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = ballCategory
```

Hopefully you can translate it to objective C if you are using that.